# How to write a basic Pymc3 model? A minor substitution in the tutorial is problematic

Tags: python, statistics, bayesian, pymc3, mcmc

I'm trying to infer 2 parameters (beta and gamma) given a deterministic equation and simulated noisy data. For some reason, the equation I'm using seems to be problematic, as I just copied the basic pymc3 tutorial and used my own deterministic equation. Here is the model I'm using:

```
# True parameter values
beta, gamma = 0.21, 0.07

# Size of dataset
days = 50

# Predictor variable
time = np.arange(0,days,1)

# Simulate outcome variable
data = []
for t in time:
    data.append((beta/((beta-gamma))*(np.exp(t*(beta-gamma))-1)+1) + np.random.normal(0,1))

basic_model = pm.Model()

def smodel(beta,gamma):
    s = beta/((beta-gamma))*(tt.exp(time*(beta-gamma))-1)+1
    return s

with basic_model:

    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    beta = pm.Normal("beta", mu=0, sigma=10)
    gamma = pm.Normal("gamma", mu=0, sigma=10)

    # Expected value of outcome
    #smodel_pm = pm.Deterministic('smodel', smodel(inputParam))
    y_obs = pm.Normal('obs', mu=smodel(beta,gamma), sigma=1,observed=data)
    
    # Draw the specified number of samples
    trace = pm.sample(step=pm.Metropolis())
```

However, when I run a summary of the trace, I'm getting 0's for everything. Anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

The parameterization is rather poor here (correlated variables, symmetric solutions in domain), plus Metropolis-Hastings simply needs to run for a long time, whereas the default settings assume NUTS.

Here's a suggested alternative parameterization, plus tuning and draw counts more reasonable for this sampling strategy:

```python
basic_model = pm.Model()

def smodel(a, b):
    s = a*(tt.exp(b*time)-1)+1
    return s

with basic_model:

    # priors for pre-transformed model parameters
    a = pm.Normal("a", mu=0, sigma=10)
    b = pm.HalfNormal("b", sigma=10)
    
    # (transformed) parameters of interest
    beta  = pm.Deterministic("beta", a*b)
    gamma = pm.Deterministic("gamma", (a-1)*b)
    
    # expected value of outcome
    y_obs = pm.Normal('obs', mu=smodel(a, b), sigma=1, observed=data)
    
    # Draw the specified number of samples
    trace = pm.sample(step=pm.Metropolis(), tune=100000, draws=50000)
```

One could probably up the `draws` even further, since the effective sample sizes (ESS) are so small, but the numbers for the parameters of interest are about where they should be:

[image]

Looking at the pairs plots, one can see the correlation for `a,b` is still very high, which explains the samples are so highly auto-correlated.

[image]

The traces and densities (per chain) look decent to me:

[image]